# Visual C++ 2010 cannot include files

Tags: visual-c++

Okay, so I've had this problem for a while and I've tried to fix it with no success. I've been trying to get into C++ from my C# knowledge and when I try to build and run a simple "Hello World" program, it fails. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World! ";
  return 0;
}
```

And the errors:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "iostream"
IntelliSense: name must be a namespace name
IntelliSense: identifier "cout" is undefined
```

I checked the included directory, there are only four files:

- omp.h
- pgobootrun.h
- svr.h
- wmiatprov.h

The lib directory has only four lib files:

- pgobootrun.lib
- pgort.lib
- vcomp.lib
- vcopmd.lib

I've reinstalled at least 3 times with no success.
I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: What version of VC are you using? Did you set up your IDE properly?

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention the empty include and lib directories. And it's Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: Try to install Windows SDK

Comment: I just tried to, it failed...

Comment: I already have Windows SDK v7.0A

Comment: Search for `iostream` on your computer, if found, try to set up the path to include in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Your registry contains junk from a previous install of VS2010.  So when you installed it again, it skipped the sub-task for VC++.  Hard to fix, you need a cleanup utility to get rid of the junk.  Google "vs2010 install cleanup" to get some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

the error is related to a "url" issue when you are compiling the code Move it to one of the standard directories. You could also add the path to the list of directories in your compiler.
also i'm assuming you're using visual studio ? try this as well.

The error is due to the fact that Visual Studio can compile multiple projects at one time. The generated sample solutions contain two projects that use common files. It is common for instances of the compiler to attempt to reference the same file at the same time.

To avoid running into this problem, you can do one of the following steps:

- Do not build the entire solution. Instead, build each application
  separately.
- Configure Visual Studio to set the maximum number of parallel builds
  to one (1): Select Tools, Options. In the Options dialog,
- expand Projects and Solutions, select Build and Run. Set the maximum
  number of parallel project builds to 1.
- Add a dependency between the projects in the .sln file: In the
  solution explorer window, right click the solution, select Project
  Dependencies. In the Project Dependencies dialog, set one of the
  projects to be dependent on the other.

hope that helps let me know

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it. I uninstalled vs2010 and deleted the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" folder in "Program Files (x86)". Then I opened up regedit and deleted the one in there too. Then I reinstalled and now the include and lib directories are full again. The program ran successfully too.